# How to simplify root over root expressions?

Tags: radicals

How is $\sqrt{9+2\sqrt6+2\sqrt8+2\sqrt{12}}$ simplified into $\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt4$ ?

Comment: $$9=2+3+4,\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$$ for $a,b\ge0$

Comment: I guess they expect you to recognize and thus use backwards the formula of the square of a trinomial.

Comment: One does not have to recognize it, it could be derived $(a+b+c)^2 = \cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the observation that
$$(\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt4)^2=2+3+4+2\sqrt2\sqrt3+2\sqrt2\sqrt4+2\sqrt3\sqrt4=9+2\sqrt6+2\sqrt8+2\sqrt{12}.$$